# How to measure Sails.js requests/respond time

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I would like to see in the console the time it takes for an HTTP request to be responded. Kind of like express.js does.

`GET api/myurl/ 210ms 200`

I run `sails debug` but this doesn't show much.
I have node-inspector running but it seems this lets me inspect the JavaScript objects at runtime but not this particular thing.
Is there a configuration in Sails I can enable or a NPM module I can install to find out this time between request and response?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to measure total response time (including view generation and pushing data to socket) you can use *req._startTime* defined in *startRequestTimer* middleware or use [response-time](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time) middleware which gives much more accurate results.

This middleware adds a *X-Response-Time* header to all HTTP responses so you can check it both on client and server side.

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: [
      'responseTimeLogger',
      // ...
    ],

    // Using built-in variable defined by Sails
    responseTimeLogger: function (req, res, next) {
      req.on("end", function() {
        sails.log.info('response time: ' + new Date() - req._startTime + 'ms');
      });
      next();
    },

    // Using response-time middleware
    responseTimeLogger: function (req, res, next) {
      req.on("end", function() {
        sails.log.info('response time: ' + res.getHeader('X-Response-Time'));
      });
      require('response-time')()(req, res, next);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What should be the order for that case, in `config/http.js` I got an order array with other middlewares

Comment: If possible, response time logger should be at the top of the list.

Comment: I've created a hook that adds all the things needed. Check my answer below

Answer (score 6):

@abeja's answer is great, but a little out of date. In case of anyone still seek the answer, I put the latest version below:

```
// Using response-time middleware
responseTimeLogger: function(req, res, next) {
  res.on("finish", function() {
    sails.log.info("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url, res.get('X-Response-Time'));
  });
  require('response-time')()(req, res, next);
}
```

A little explanation:

1. Listen to `finish` event of `res` object, because when `req` emit `end` event, `res` header is not set yet.
2. Recent Node.js change the API `getHeader` to `get`.

btw, my reputation is 0, so I can't post comment to the @abeja's answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @abeja answer (very nice answer though), if you are looking for production application monitoring, you might be interested in [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/).

The tool helps you to measure (among other things) response time, throughput, error rates etc.

[image: New Relic Transactions]

It also measures database performance (in my case it is MongoDB) and help you easily investigate bottlenecks.

[image]

On top of that it allows you to measure application performance from a browser (including connection time, DOM rendering time etc.)

New Relic setup is very easy - a few steps to have your stats running (more here: [Installing and maintaining Node.js](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/installing-maintaining-nodejs)). For development purposes you can also have free of charge account with 24hr data retention.

I hope that will also help.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I will not make it the correct answer since the answer by @abeja was the one i was looking for. But it is a very important addition to monitoring nodejs performance. :)

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic statistics solution (which could be used in your Sails.js project as well) there's a great series of tutorials on digitalocean on using StatsD with Graphite to measure anything (and everything) on your server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-tracking-statistics-with-graphite-statsd-and-collectd

There's also a nice StatsD node.js client called Lynx: https://github.com/dscape/lynx along with an express middleware for Lynx to measure counts and response times for express routes: https://github.com/rosskukulinski/lynx-express (Sails is fully compatible with Express/Connect middleware)

I'm planning to use this soon on my sails project before going to production, will update this with more details when I do, let me know if you go ahead before I do..

Comment: This seems also very useful. Are all of these tools free/opensource? New relic seems so cool and easy to install but 150/m is too much right now.

Comment: Yes :) and the beauty of these tools is that they're completely customizable, they're opensource, in fact, you build everything (almost) from scratch, like what to track and how to track it, luckily there's lynx-express for standard express/sails routes tracking, but you can also add and customize that.

I'm currently using the free version of newrelic, but i'm not completely satisfied, will be looking to this solution once I have more time.

Comment: Also remember that graphite is an extremely powerful presentation engine.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Sails Hook that eases the whole process. Just install it using `npm install sails-hook-responsetime --save` and it will add X-Response-Time to both HTTP and Socket requests.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-responsetime